# How to use custom Contact data in Segmentation rules in the List Manager

Tags: xdb, list-manager

I have varied information stored in `xDB` imported from a CRM system. This is stored against `Contacts` in custom `Facets`. What is the most scalable method to use this data for segmenting large number of Contact's in the `List Manager`?

Creating the custom segmentation rules isn't a problem it's more retrieving that getting that Contact data in a scalable way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sitecore 8.1 update 3 brought a change that allows custom `Contact` Data to be indexed. This means this Custom Contact data will be available to searched through the `sitecore_analytics_index`.

This is implemented through a custom `processor` that extends the new `contactindexable.loadfields` `pipeline`. This allows data from custom xDB facets to be added to the collection of contact indexable fields.

```cs
protected override IEnumerable<IIndexableDataField> GetFields(ContactIndexableLoadFieldsPipelineArgs args)
{
  var fields = new List<IIndexableDataField>();
  var customFacet = args.Contact.GetFacet<ICustomContactFacet>("CustomContactFacetName");
  if (customFacet != null)
  {
    fields.Add(new IndexableDataField<bool>("contact.CustomFieldName", customFacet.CustomField));
  }
  return fields;
}
```

I have since written a detailed [blog post on how to do this](https://jonathanrobbins.co.uk/2017/01/03/index-custom-xdb-facets-to-segment-contacts-in-sitecore-list-manager/)

Comment: Ok, and how then I create a custom rule condition for the segmented list? How to retrieve that indexed value in the rule? Can I put custom objects into IndexableDataField? like `fields.Add(new IndexableDataField<ICustomElement>("contact.CustomElement", customFacet.CustomElement));`